# I encountered a problem about c++ with opencv

Tags: opencv, c++11

> error: expected identifier before ‘int’

```
#define INT int
```

my code :

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
#define CHAR char
#define UCHAR unsigned char
#define UINT unsigned int
#define DWORD unsigned int
#define PVOID void*
#define ULONG unsigned int
```

i don't know how to deal with it

Comment: please show the whole code

Comment: What is the relation with opencv?

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
#define INT int
```

and follow it with:

```
#define UINT unsigned int
```

this gets translated by the pre-processor to:

```
#define U int unsigned int
```

and then you get:

> error: expected identifier before ‘int’

Solution:

Change the  order of the `#define` lines.